# Background Opacity (USING RGBA)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make something simple here, but its getting me confused.

If I have this in my css.

```
.body {
    width: 150px; height: 40px; padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);  text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    display: block; top: 50px;
    font-weight: bold; font-size: 25px;
}
```

And I want to change the opacity when you click on a button and I have this in my HTML:

```
<button onclick="lessColour()">-Colour</button>
```

How can I create this lessColour() function so everytime I click on the button, it will decrease the alpha in rgba by 0.1?

Comment: It is getting down voted because there is no code example. You should show what you have attempted.

Comment: Much better. When you post try to add code and to show what efforts you have made to find a solution. Other wise your question will quickly be down voted then removed from the site.

Answer (score 2):

rgba doesn't take precents. it takes a value between 0-1;

rgba format:

```
rgba([0-255], [0-255], [0-255], [0.00-1.00])
```

example:

```
rgba(120, 200, 10, 0.80)
```

Comment: I know, if you see the picture, I am actually using it.

Comment: @JoãoChokitu Yeah i just looked it over. I think it might not be possible to give the <body> tag opacity less than 1? since it is the "root" layer.

Comment: Yea, I just don't really know what to do, do you have ideas to change a color opacity?

Comment: @JoãoChokitu Must it be the body tag? perhaps a container/wrapper div holding the main content of your app would do instead? I don't understand though: why would you want to put an opacity setting on the first layer? There's nothing behind it so there's no point in that right? Maybe you can give me more details on the project and we can see a different tactic to handling it?